# Custom window snapping layout for windows on Ubuntu/OSX/Windows

Tags: windows, macos, ubuntu, window, desktop

I'm using a 50" 4k monitor and I love it, but I want to be able to create a "hotspot" layout for my windows to snap to. This is also useful for just about any screen size. Splitting up my screen into four quarters isn't sufficient, which is the maximum that can be done with Ubuntu's, Window's, and OSX's native settings.

For example, in Windows, there is https://maxto.net/, or, if you have a Dell monitor, Dell's "EasyArrange".

If you know software that accomplishes this for Windows, OSX, and Ubuntu, please list them.

Comment: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8768022